# Custom Source for XmlDataProvider in WPF

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following in my app. config file

```
  <appSettings>
  <add key="Path" value="C:\Users\dave\Desktop\dave"/>
   </appSettings>
```

in my XAML file, the XmlDataProvider is as follows:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Name="Data" Source= "setting.xml" XPath="Product" />
```

I would like to point the Source to Path.

Any help as always is much appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: You will have to read the application setting from your configuration file and then you can bind the `Source` property to the value of the `Path` key.

Comment: It's easy in C#. Is that acceptable? Or with a complete filename in ApppSettings

Comment: Thank you Bernard. Henk, C# is acceptable, I have used it like string xmlPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]; but I do not know who to use it with the XAML. I tried Source = xmlPath + "setting.xml" Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you dont mind having a property in code behind, you can use `StringFormat` in the xaml

```
public string MyPath
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]; }
}


<XmlDataProvider x:Name="Data" Source="{Binding Path=MyPath, StringFormat={}{0}\\Settings.xml}" XPath="Product" />
```

returns: "C:\Users\dave\Desktop\dave\Settings.xml"

Comment: Hi Sa_ddam. Thank you for your help. I can see how this can work, however I'm getting the following error. Do you know why this may be? A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'XmlDataProvider'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Name="Data" Source= "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/setting.xml" XPath="Product" />
```

setting.xml must be in your main folder.